# fixed or sticky the header background image up to the specific section only

Tags: javascript, html, css

how could I fixed or sticky the header background image up to the first section only?
let's say this is the code:

```
<header id="header-bg"> <!-- inside this id has a background cover img -->
     <!-- header content here -->
</header>

<section id="first-section">
     <!-- content here -->
</section>
```

my goal is to stay/fixed or sticky the header background up to the first section when scrolling. once the first section is end, the header background is not fixed/sticky anymore.

Comment: There isn't such thing as sticky background images. only `background-attachment: fixed;`, unless you mean making the header itself sticky. As for the issue, what have you tried so far? I'm pretty confident it would require dealing with scroll events, because the scroll position on an element cannot really affect another element with pure CSS, not to mention that elements cannot affect the elements above them with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have created a sandbox for your reference.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-lake-hklc5?file=/index.html

```css
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header class="header" id="header-bg">
    <!-- inside this id has a background cover img -->
    <!-- header content here -->
    Header Content Dummy
  </header>

  <section id="first-section">
    <!-- content here -->
    Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes
    here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content
    goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first
    content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here
  </section>
</section>
<section id="first-section">
  <!-- content here -->
  Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes
  here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content
  goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content
  goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here
</section>
<section id="first-section">
  <!-- content here -->
  Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes
  here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content
  goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content
  goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here
</section>
<section id="first-section">
  <!-- content here -->
  Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes
  here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content
  goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content
  goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here
</section>
<section id="first-section">
  <!-- content here -->
  Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes
  here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content
  goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content
  goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here Section first content goes here
</section>
```

Comment: hi @prograk you just used css only? and that's it? no javascript etc?

Comment: no javascript css has position sticky

Answer (score 0):

i think using js to change position to fixed or sticky after your required amount of scrolling to change the position.